# bootstrap tab toggle isn't working properly (only toggle once, cannot toggle back)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, toggle

I am currently helping to solve a toggle problem but there's no error showing in console and I don't know where to start looking.
There are two tabs which can be toggled between each other.  Let's say toggle tabs are pay / method.  Default page is showing pay and when method tab is clicked, method tab shows perfectly but when clicking pay again the tab (CSS) worked fine that we can see pay tab is active but contents of pay doesn't show.  The contents are still method.

Currently using bootstrap and of course the script included jquery already.

The html code is

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
<li class="active" role="presentation">
<a data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="home" href="#home" aria-expanded="true">Pay</a>
</li>
<li class="" role="presentation">
<a data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="method" href="#method" aria-expanded="false">Pay</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

I am not sure what else to show since the scripts is form bootstrap, it'll be HUGE.

P.S. as said, even though the contents don't show but by clicking each other, I can still see the class is set to active and aria-expanded is set to true to whichever tab I clicked. (Also, I am wondering if I couldn't find out what is really causing this since there are no errors and so on, am I able to write a new script and include the script below the bootstrap script?  That should override and work right?)

Comment: you didn't put closing `</li>` tags

Comment: @Luka oops that's typo

Comment: Have you included scripts in proper sequence?

Comment: yes I did but I figured (well not figured, founded help but it's weird) I just had to add `data-target` and use it the same way as `href` attribute then it will toggle perfectly.  I had been looking at some tab toggle example for bootstrap but and I followed their example to create the html above I still have no idea where went wrong but at least the `data-target` saved me